# jQuery issue in IE

Tags: javascript

This function works fine in Chrome but not working in IE, I'm not able to access `$(".availabilityLightbox")` in IE but it works fine in Chrome, pls suggest some aletnatives so that I can use this function in both Chrome and IE.

```
{
  var  url1 ='<@core.basePath/>sp/availability/populate';
  $(".availabilityLightbox").dialog('close');
  $(".availabilityLightbox").dialog('destroy');
    $(".availabilityLightbox")
        .html("Loading...")
        .load(url1, null, function(responseText){
            $('.availabilityLightbox').dialog({
                autoOpen: true, 
                modal: true,
                position: top,
                resizable:'false',
                close: function() {

                },width: 920,zIndex: 3999 
            });
            $(".ui-dialog-titlebar").hide();
            $(".ui-dialog").css("margin-top","151px");
            $(".ui-dialog").css("margin-bottom","101px");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found with the (excellent) Colorbox lightbox that new versions of jQuery often break it. The guy is on the ball though and downloading the latest Colorbox solves any issues. You may want to check your version of jQuery and the plug in are up-to-date or in synch.

Another thing to do would be to look in Chrome's console for any error messages. Maybe it is seem problems but reacting as IE does by freaking out.

Comment: I'm sorry, but its not working, can you please tell me some other alternative for this.